# NSImage equivalent of ImageMagick#export_pixels

Tags: ios, macos, swift, imagemagick

I'm looking at finding an equivalent NSData output from NSImage (and/or UIImage) that [ImageMagick#export_pixels](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image2.html#export_pixels) would produce.

The end goal is to MD5 hash the resulting NSData to compare it to a MD5 hash generated from the bytes produced by the image magick function.  (background: I have md5 hashes of the image magic pixel data already created and saved from files.  If I load those same files into an iOS/OSX app, I want to produce an md5 hash to quickly check if the file has been seen before)

I would like to do it native to iOS/OSX without pulling in the ImageMagick library directly (if possible), but I'm new to the iOS/OSX libraries/frameworks, and would certainly appreciate some guidance.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the raw bytes of a UIImage this way :

```
CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage);
NSData* data = (id)CFBridgingRelease(CGDataProviderCopyData(provider));
const uint8_t* bytes = [data bytes];
```

or if you want to just get the NSData out of a UIImage you can do it this way :

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, compression);
```